# How to calculate percentage existence

Tags: pandas-groupby

```
pets = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Izzy':['Smith','cat',1],\
                   'Lynx':['Smith','cat',9],\
                   'Oreo':['Smith','dog',7],\
                   'Archie':['Mack','dog',3], \
                   'Prim':['Mack','cat',1], \
                    'Fern':['Somers','cat',12]}, orient='index')
pets.columns=['family', 'type','age']


        family  type    age
Izzy    Smith   cat     1
Lynx    Smith   cat     9
Oreo    Smith   dog     7
Archie  Mack    dog     3
Prim    Mack    cat     1
Fern    Somers  cat     12
```

I want to calculate the average age of each type of pet across all families, and also the percentage of families that own each type of pet.  So I'm starting with this, which is easy.

```
pets.groupby(by='type').mean()

    age
type    
cat 5.75
dog 5.00
```

But not sure how to get the second number, in this case 100% for cats, and 67% for dogs. I'm sure I can get there in several steps, but is there an easy way to do this in the same groupby?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x = pets.groupby("type")["family"].nunique() / pets["family"].nunique() * 100
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
type
cat    100.000000
dog     66.666667
Name: family, dtype: float64
```